# Configure new IMAP mail account in IOS 10

Tags: email, imap, ios

I am trying to configure a new mail account for IMAP.

In iOS 10, I go `Settings` > `Mail` > `Accounts` > `Add Account` > `Other` > `Add Mail Account`. After I supply my Email and password at this time, iOS seems to attempt connecting with POP and if this works (which is the case) does not offer IMAP as a choice. So how can I configure an IMAP mail account with iOS 10?

Comment: It could also be autodiscovery thats problematic for your domain. Do you have a DNS SRV record: _autodiscover._tcp.yourdomain? Is it your domain, or some public domain (ie hotmail) that apple might configure differently (as pop)?

Comment: @Niklas it is a public domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine doesn't do that - maybe it fails to connect over POP for some reason.
However - try putting in the wrong password - it'll fail to connect and should present you with the manual server options so you can input everything yourself.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thx.